# Using ThreadPools to process M tasks of N users on K threads (N*M >> K) in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor, graceful-degradation, qos

I have a RESTful-styled RPC (remote procedure call) API running on a tomcat server that processes data of N users with M tasks on K threads. Mostly one user has around 20 to 500 tasks (but M could be between 1 to 5000). One task needs around 10 to 20 seconds to complete, but can be between 1 second and 20 minutes. Currently, mostly the system has one user, sometimes up to three, but it increases to around 10 users at the same time in the near future. Our server has 10 cores, therefore I'd like to use 10 threads. At the moment every user gets 5 threads for processing, which works fine. But a) most of the time the machine is only utilized 50% (which results in needles waiting in the "30-minute" range), sometimes the server load is up to 150%.

Requirements to solution:

1. at all times the server is utilized to 100% (if there are tasks)
2. that all users are treated the same regarding thread execution (same amount of threads finished as every other user)
3. a new user does not have to wait until all tasks of a earlier user are done (especially in the case where user1 has 5000 tasks and user2 has 1 this is important)

Solutions that come to mind:

1. just use a FixedThreadPoolExecutor with 10 threads, violates condition 3
2. use the PriorityBlockingQueue and implement the compareTo method in my task -> can not use the threadpoolExecutors submit method (and therefore I do not know when a submitted task is over)
3. implement a "round robin" like blocking queue, where the K threads (in our case 10) take new tasks from the N internal queues in a round robin way -> to be able to put a task into the right queue, I need a "submit"-method that takes more than one parameter (I need to implement a ThreadPoolExecutor, too)

I tried to make an illustration of what I mean by round robin like blocking queue (if not helpful feel free to edit it out):

> ```
>   --                       --
>   --        --        --   --             queue task load, 
>   --   --   --   --   --   --        --   one task denoted by --
>   --   --   --   --   --   --   --   -- 
> | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4 | Q5 | Q6 | Q7 | QN |
> |                      *   ^            |
> |                  last|   |next        |
> |                           -------------
> \                          /
>  \    |    |    |    |    |
>  | T1 | T2 | T3 | T4 | TK |
> ```

Is there an elegant solution to use mostly Java standard APIs (or any other widespread Java API) for achieving this kind of processing behavior (might it be one of my proposed solutions or any another solution)? Or do you have any other hints on how to tackle this issue?

Comment: As far as i understand `java.util.concurrent.Executor`, every `ThreadPool` is bound to one `Executor` and vice-versa (in fact, you don't even see the `ThreadPool`, only the `Executor`). You cannot ask the `Executor`, how many tasks are unfinished. By some bookkeeping, you could calculate the number of tasks finished after an `Executor` is finished. Maybe you can use a a `Priority(Blocking)Queue<ExecutorService>` and sort it by the amount of tasks finished per user.

Comment: Requirement #2 may not be neccessary. If one user has only one task and another has five, it may be fair to give the second one more thread (CPU resources) than the first one. What you really want to achieve is a minimum waiting time between submitting a task and getting the result, as a sum over all tasks for all users. can you estimate the time a task will take to finish?

@Turing85: Sometimes it is better to use `ThreadPool`s directly. The `Executor` convenience factory is really only for programmers who can't be bothered with details.

Comment: A few questions I have with your solution.  1. What if all queues are empty, how would you wait for a task to be available? 2. What if your queue is empty then you start round robin, 5 seconds later your queue is no longer empty and the other queues are very full?

Answer (score 0):

If you agree that minimizing the overall task latency is a good replacement for requirements 2 and 3, and you have good-enough task runtime estimates, then I may have an answer.

You store the task submit time with each task, so that later you can always compute its estimated latency. 
You can then build a PriorityBlockingQueue that, when inserting a new task, always inserts it at a queue position that provides some fairness and attempts to minimize overall latency. This will, at first, put long-running tasks at a disadvantage. I have not tried it myself, but I would assign a task priority based on your estimated run time, and use estimatedRuntime-waitingTime as priority (taking the lowest-priotity job first). This will give heavy tasks a chance after they waited enough to have negative priority. Until then, light tasks will have a better chance to be first, even if they have just been submitted. This scheduling will only be so fair as your estimates allow, though.

As for the round-robin requirement: If that is really important, you can handle this in the queue as well. Basically, when you use a thread pool, you can implement yur scheduling strategy in terms of where you insert new jobs in the queue. If you can estimate job latency, you can balance that across your users, too, by inserting at the right position.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing your requirements:

1) maximizing thread usage: any ThreadPoolExecutor will take care of this.
2) all users are treated the same: essentially requires a round-robin setup.
3) avoid new users waiting in FIFO order: same as #2.

Also you mentioned the ability to submit and get a result.

You might consider a standalone `PriorityBlockingQueue<Job>` using a wrapper object, e.g.:

```
class Job implements Comparable<Job> {
    private int priority;
    private YourCallable task;

    public Job(int priority, YourCallable task) {
        this.priority = priority;
        this.task = task;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Job job) {
        // use whatever order you prefer, based on the priority int
    }
}
```

Your producer offers a Job to the PriorityBlockingQueue with a priority assigned (based on your round-robin rule or whatever), and a task that implements Callable.  Your consumer then does queue.poll for a Job.

Once you have that in hand, you can grab the task contained inside that Job object and send it off for processing on a ThreadPoolExecutor of your choosing.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on a solution similar to the round-robin setup. It gets complicated real fast but I think I came up with a decent implementation. It is probably not a very elegant solution but there are unit-tests showing some functions. Unfortunately, [TaskQ](https://github.com/fwi/TaskQ/tree/master/taskq) is not yet at a "1.0" stage.

It does cover your points 1 to 3:

- you can specify the amount of threads to use and if there are enough tasks, all threads are used.
- each user will get a turn as threads become available
- if one user A has 500 tasks in queue and another user B comes along with 1 task, the task from user B will get executed as soon as a thread is available.

There is no manual/documentation yet, I hope you can find the time to investigate. A unit test showing some usage is [here](https://github.com/fwi/TaskQ/blob/master/taskq/taskq-core/src/test/java/nl/fw/taskq/TestTaskQWithQos.java), the main class to extend/use is [RunnableTaskQWithQos](https://github.com/fwi/TaskQ/blob/master/taskq/taskq-core/src/main/java/nl/fw/taskq/RunnableTaskQWithQos.java).